# Give Specific Space on string

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, string

i have string variable on my VB.net which came from Stored Procedure, after put it on variable , i want to make the values have specified Space.

the rule is like this

[image]

the number on the image mean spaces,

i already do some trial and error like this :

```
                Dim words As String() = receiptText.Split(" ")
                Dim word As String
                Dim XMLBuild As New StringBuilder
                XMLBuild.Append(Space(9))
                For Each word In words

                    XMLBuild.Append(word)
                    XMLBuild.Append(Space(9))

                Next
```

but the result is

```
{         PLEASE         KEEP         THIS         RECEIPT         AS         VALID         PROOF         OF         PAYMENT         }
```

not like the rule that i should do. is there any string function i shold use ?

Comment: `PadLeft` or `PadRight`

Comment: `padLeft on? so far i know that pad left is to give or insert something... is it possible to use it on my case?

Comment: Did you even google the term? Search `C# PadLeft` and see what it's all about. It's everything you need.

Comment: okay im sorry, i already use em.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You split your input string to every space, I am not sure that this is a good approach because the person names, city address and other fields have spaces in between words, however if you want to format yours input in a fixed space area then I will give you a general approach, at least for the first line of your example above

```
' This is how the first line appears in the string array after the space splitting'
Dim parts = new string() {"BL", "TH", ":", "NO",  "REF.", ":", "1234567890", "R.WAHYUDIYOINO,IR"}

' This array contains the spaces reserved for each word in the string array above'
Dim spaces = new integer () {3,9,2,17,10,2,17,2,28 }

' Now loop on the strings and format them as indicated by the spaces'
' Attention, the value for space include the string itself'
Dim sb = new StringBuilder()
Dim x As INteger = 0
For each s in parts
    sb.Append(s.PadRight(spaces(x)))
    x += 1
Next
sb.AppendLine()
' To check the result (it is useful only if the output window has fixed space font)'
sb.Append("12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890")
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString())
```

Comment: Awsome, it is what i looking for. thak youuu :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**String.Join**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/57a79xd0.aspx) to accomplish your requirement,

```
String.Join(Space(9), receiptText.Split(Space(1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you need your values to be concanated and to be of a specific length. This is easily done with the use of the `format` function and the `PadLeft`/`PadRight`.

First, you put everything in a format string. But each variable is passed to a padding function.

```
String strFinalResult = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", str1.PadRight(9), str2.PadRight(6), str3.PadRight(7));
```

The number in the PadRight function is the total lenght of your string. So if your variable is "abc" and you call str.PadRight(9), you will get "abc" with 6 space on the right.

Hope it helps!

***EDIT***
My answer is in C# but since it's the String object, I'm pretty sure it's available in VB.NET

***EDIT 2***
If you want your string to have both padding at the beginning and at the end, you can use PadRight and PadLeft.